# Jquery serialize is getting same value for dynamic text boxes

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am using following code to create dynamic text boxes with a check box.

```
function addNewModifier()
    {
        $('#modifiersList tr:last').after('<tr><td></td><td><form id="insertModifier"><input name="modifierName" id="modifierName" class="focused form-control" type="text"></input></td><td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" style = "cursor:pointer"></span></td><td><input name="status" id="status" type="checkbox"></input></td><td align="center"><span class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveNewModifier()"><i class="icon-white fa-plus-circle fa fa-align-left"></i>Save</span></td><td><span class="btn btn-default" onclick="deleteNewSuperCategory(this)"><i class="icon-white fa-plus-circle fa fa-align-left"></i>Cancel</span></td></form></tr>'); 
    }
```

By using above function I add new row in a table and then on clicking on save button I need form data .

And my save function is follows.

```
function saveNewModifier()
    {
        var groupName = $("#insertModifier").serialize();
        alert(groupName);
    }
```

The above `saveNewModifier()` function only gives textbox value and that is always same .

Please help me how can I get value of both check box and text box always different on creating new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. this might help you

```js
function saveNewModifier()
    {
        var groupName = $("#insertModifier").serialize();
        var checkValue = $("#status").serialize();
        alert(groupName);
        alert(checkValue);
        
    }
function addNewModifier()
    {
        $('#modifiersList tr:last').after('<tr><td></td><td><form id="insertModifier"><input name="modifierName" id="modifierName" class="focused form-control" type="text"></input></td><td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" style = "cursor:pointer"></span></td><td><input name="status" id="status" type="checkbox"></input></td><td align="center"><span class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave"><i class="icon-white fa-plus-circle fa fa-align-left"></i>Save</span></td><td><span class="btn btn-default" onclick="deleteNewSuperCategory(this)"><i class="icon-white fa-plus-circle fa fa-align-left"></i>Cancel</span></td></form></tr>'); 
        $(this).serialize();
    }


addNewModifier();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSave").on('click', function() {
       saveNewModifier();
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="modifiersList">
    <tr><td>Dummy Data</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Here is the exact solution of your problem** [click here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/cpxg5o8r/1/)

```
function saveNewModifier()
    {
        var groupName = $("#insertModifier").serialize();
        var checkValue = $("#status").serialize();
        alert(groupName);
        alert(checkValue);

    };

function addNewModifier()
    {
$('#modifiersList tr:last').after('<tr><td></td><td><form id="insertModifier"><input name="modifierName" id="modifierName" class="focused form-control" type="text"></input></td><td align="center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" style = "cursor:pointer"></span></td><td><input name="status" id="status" type="checkbox"></input></td><td align="center"><span class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave"><i class="icon-white fa-plus-circle fa fa-align-left"></i>Save</span></td><td><span class="btn btn-default" onclick="deleteNewSuperCategory(this)"><i class="icon-white fa-plus-circle fa fa-align-left"></i>Cancel</span></td></form></tr>'); 
    };



$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('click', '#btnSave', function() {
       saveNewModifier();
    });
});
```

---

```
<table id="modifiersList">
    <tr><td onclick="addNewModifier();">add new html</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not correct , just try to add new rows twice and you will see the value is always same after every save. And this for what I am looking for solution.

Comment: if you need to add multiple rows then you should have to make ids dynamic (id should be unique on a page). go to the link for the solution https://fiddle.jshell.net/cpxg5o8r/3/

Comment: Thanks , this is what I was looking for . Works great!